# How to create a Gridview in iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone

I want to create a Grid view with images in iPhone programmatically. Pls do give me some example for it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265293/grid-view-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the rows and columns of images and set the `UIImage` instance's frame origin some offset-multiple of your image or image-cell width.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I want to place buttons as images so that i can perform some action on click of the button.How should i do that? If u have any links to such example pls give it?

Comment: Search Google on `UIButton`. You can attach a `UIImage` to a `UIButton` and set a button's action when tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be easier to use Three20 component. There is Photo Viewer for displaying images in grid, which "emulates Apple's Photos app with all of its flick n' pinch delight".