# grid-like control for iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, aqgridview

Is there any grid-like control in iPad SDK?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grid view in iPhone SDK ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265293/grid-view-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the UIKit, no. Depending on your needs, you could probably set up a `UITableView` to use `UITableViewCell`s that have extra labels for additional "columns". If you need something more like spreadsheet, you'll need to write something custom.

Comment: Can I select just one column if I use this approach ? Or when I click on a column the entir row is selected ?

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [AQGridView](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)

Answer (score 0):

As a commercial alternative, I would recommend giving the ShinobiControls a try. They have just launched [ShinobiGrids](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobigrids/). These grids are high performance and have some nice interactive touches, columns and row dragging for example.

*As a **full disclosure**, I work for Scott Logic which is the parent company for ShinobiControls.*