# How to design and create a GridView using UIScrollView or UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, gridview, uiscrollview

I think GridView is a very common view in many situation. As a beginner in iOS, I just wonder why iOS didn't provide a GridView class.
So here's my question, how to design and create a GridView using UIScrollView or UITableView?
or is there some other solution to create a GridView?

Comment: in ios you can create a uitableview with only one column so you cannot able to create a uitable with multiple columns. If u want to do you can create a uitableview with detailed view

Comment: As Michal K. said, search GitHub. or if you want to make your own, then make a custom UITableViewCell subclass, with the extra views added.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grid view in iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265293/grid-view-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: In iOS6 Apple added UICollectionView: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html. Someone has also kindly backported it to iOS4.3+: https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GitHub is the best place to search for open source solutions, so try to use it next time. Check [DTGridView](https://github.com/danielctull/DTGridView) or [PF-GridView](https://github.com/pettyfun/pf-gridview)

Answer (score 7):

This question has been asked before:
[Grid view in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265293/grid-view-in-iphone-sdk)

Personally I recommend [AQGridView](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView).

Comment: Just spent some time playing with AQGridView and it seems to be very buggy, so I would not recommend.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UICollectionView to create a nice gridview. It's simple to use. It is available in iOS 6.0 and later.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview

Answer (score 0):

So I have been delving into this over the past few days and there are a few more options that I have found worthwhile (some of these other posters have already mentioned, but I am mentioning again for completeness):

https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView (Free)

http://ioscomponents.com/Home/Products (Commercial - lots of features 29 USD)

https://www.developergarden.com/en/marketplace/components/details/cmp/ios-data-grid-table-view (commercial 129 USD)

http://www.binpress.com/app/vertical-horizontal-scrolling-datagrid-for-ios/1082 (Commercial 129 USD)

Infragistics has one too: http://www.infragistics.com/products/ios USD 295 (USD 995 if you want support).