# Creating Image Grid using UITableView in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Here i need the grid layout for creating similar to the photo album page,But in that page i am having thousands of images so that, i am using uitableview

Comment: check  out https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a custom cell extending `UITableViewCell`.

Add UIImageView to it. assign images on  `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 6):

GridView can be done using `UITableView`. One way u can do it is have a custom UITableViewCell & have 2 imageViews with tag 1 & 2. That way when u access that view in `cellForRowIndex...` you can extract that imageView & populate...

You can do this or u can use what others have already done  -

[how to design and create a GridView using UIScrollView or UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140710/how-to-design-and-create-a-gridview-using-uiscrollview-or-uitableview)

[How To Create A Gallery on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866766/how-to-create-a-gallery-on-ios)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430012/ios-grid-view-with-section-headers