# create 15 image into an scrollerview 4 rows * 4 columns

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I create 15 imagebutton into an scrollerview,but have only 1 columns,
i want to change row for  (4 rows * 4 columns)

How can i do that?? Please give me some advance,Thank you..

```
NSUInteger booknumber;
for (booknumber = 1; booknumber <= 15; booknumber++) {
   UIButton *button = [self createBtn:booknumber orgx:orgx orgy:orgy];
}

orgx += 100;
orgy += 0;

orgx++;
[mFavorites addSubview:button];


- (UIButton*)createBtn:(int)day orgx:(CGFloat)orgx orgy:(CGFloat)orgy{
    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backplane.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(orgx, orgy, 75, 113);

    return button;
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I try to use for{}，but load nothing(I have no idea)，also need to study more than，please give me some advance..

Comment: Put your code up.  Questions like these make it look like you did not research and came here to get us to do your work.  At least with code, it shows you've tried.  (BTW, by even showing code, you're in the minority.  Usually, we just get these kinds of questions with no effort whatsoever on the part of the asker).

Comment: calculation of origin is not proper, every time you just increasing x, while you want a grid structure?

Comment: you can check this out for reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140710/how-to-design-and-create-a-gridview-using-uiscrollview-or-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
int booknumber = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    int orgX = i * 100;
    int orgY = j * 100;
    if (i == 3 && j == 3) return;
    UIButton *button = [self createBtn:booknumber orgx:orgX orgy:orgY];
    [mFavorites addSubview:button];
    booknumber++;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps