# How to show eight images in a table, three images in each row in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am in big trouble. Now I am going to explain to you about my problem. 
I want to show eight images in a table where three images in a row.
Please give me some clue......

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grid view in iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265293/grid-view-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: `NSLog(@"%d" 8/3)`, 2 rows??

Please improve your question, there isn't really much we can answer here

Answer (score 1):

You could use a framework that will handle all that for you.

One option you have is [Three20](http://three20.info/), another is [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView).

Three20 has go a [TTPhotoViewController](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_photo_view_controller.php) specifically aimed at implementing a multicolumn table filled with photos.

If you are not interested to all that Three20 has to offer, I would suggest going for AQGridView, anyway.