# How to add ARC for specific file?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I created a project without `ARC`. I want to use a **third party SDK** in my project. That `SDK` comes with `ARC` Support. So I want to add `ARC` for that third party files. I can disable `ARC` for all `"MYProject"` files by adding this flag into build phases like `-fno-objc-arc`.

But I may use large number of files. So it's better to add `ARC` for specific `SDK` only. So how to add ARC support for single or specific `SDK` files in `XCode` Project?

**For Instance:** I want to use Grid View. I'm adding `GMGridView` in my project and it comes with `ARC` support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable ARC for a single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523816/how-to-enable-arc-for-a-single-file)

Comment: @Leushenko It's asked before that question.

Comment: As per meta, [age doesn't matter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651). The other question is slightly clearer, although really these two are identical enough to request a merge.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Add the flag `-fobjc-arc` to the files that you'd like to use ARC. It's just the opposite of the other.

Comment: Thats great Man...Thank you so much...Can u help me to get a good toolkit for Grid View in ios with a correct documentation..I m stuck with grid view project

Comment: @DineshRaja.MaG Sorry, I don't really know any good grid view projects.

Comment: i Hope These links may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265293/grid-view-in-iphone-sdk
        
https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView

Comment: @wasim Select the project itself in the _Project Navigator_ and make sure your target is selected. Then, select the _Build Phases_ tab, open the _Compile Sources_ section and double click the _Compiler Flags_ area to add specific compiler flags to specific translation units. You can find fully detailed instructions in the Xcode Doc Set.

Answer (score 26):

You add compiler flags in Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources

Compile source show all file that project contain.so please add **-fobjc-arc** to compiler flag by double clicking on it as show in below image.

[image]