# SecKeyWrapper Error Build on device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I wanna know why I get this bunch of [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV9qJ.png) when I try to build it on device. Because I can build and run it on simulator.

[image]

Comment: It is simple as that you are using MRC in ARC environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are your targets settings? Check that ARC is disabled:

1. Select Project
2. Select Targets
3. From the right panel, select Build Settings
4. Search for "Automatic Reference Counting"

[image]

If you need to enable ARC for some files check this question [How to add ARC for specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768176/how-to-add-arc-for-specific-file)